# Easiest way to provision vm from vCenter or oVirt

Tags: virtual-machine, vcenter, ovirt

I have very less experience working on VM provisioning. As part of my current poc, I want to provision vm through API of either vcenter(VmWare) or through Ovirt(https://www.ovirt.org/). What is the easiest way to set up the ecosystem?

Answer (score 1):

Talking about oVirt, you have different methods to provision your VMs:

1. With Ansible, using official oVirt [roles](https://github.com/oVirt/ovirt-ansible) and [methods](https://github.com/oVirt/ovirt-ansible-collection);
2. With Terraform, using the [Terraform oVirt Provider plugin](https://github.com/oVirt/terraform-provider-ovirt);
3. Writing your own code, using the specific SDK for [Python](https://github.com/oVirt/ovirt-engine-sdk/blob/master/sdk/README.adoc), [Java](https://github.com/oVirt/ovirt-engine-sdk-java/blob/master/sdk/README.adoc), [Ruby](https://github.com/oVirt/ovirt-engine-sdk-ruby/blob/master/sdk/README.adoc), [Go](https://github.com/oVirt/ovirt-engine-sdk-go) or in [plain REST API](http://ovirt.github.io/ovirt-engine-api-model/) without any SDKs.